# My approach to question is not working? A problem from permutation and combinations.

Tags: permutations, combinations

> 5 Indian and 5 American couples meet at a party and shake hands. If no wife shakes hands with her husband and no Indian wife shakes hands with a male then find the number of handshakes that take place in the party.

This is how I solved.
Indian women shakes hand  with only women. So ${}^{10}C_2$ ways are possible.
Now the rest of the people( Indian men, American women and American men) can shake hands in ${}^{15}C_2$ ways. But it includes 5 hand shakes of American women with their respective husband, so it should be excluded.
Hence total number of hand shakes are
$${}^{10}C_2 + {}^{15}C_2 -5=145$$
But the answer given is 135, and following is my friend's approach.
There are 10 male and 10 female. So total hand shakes possible =${}^{20}C_2=190$.
Indian women's hand shakes with male=$({}^5C_1)*({}^{10}C_1)$=50.(It includes handshake with their respective husband also)
American women handshake with their own husband =5 ways.
So, required number of handshakes =190-50-5=135.
Now I thought a lot on both the approaches but could not point a flaw in any. Both the methods looks perfectly correct but with different answers.
Please help.

Comment: Your first $^{10}C_2$ includes handshakes of american women amongst each other which you then count again in the $^{15}C_2$.

Comment: @ Jaap Scherphuis. Thanks a lot. You nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have counted handshakes between pairs of American women twice: once in the handshakes not involving men and once in the handshakes not involving Indian women. There are $^5C_2=10$ of these, which need to be subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Number of handshakes of american woman with each other would be $^5C_2=10$. Absolutely. However second time you chose $^{15}C_2=10$ you have again took the number of second american woman so you need to subtract $^{15}C_2-^5C_2$

Comment: You can see more detailed solution of the question in https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/5-indian-and-5-american-couples-meet-at-a-party-class-10-maths-cbse-5ef9f09a97157a190a4cb0a5#:~:text=Related%20Questions-,5%20Indian%20and%205%20American%20couples%20meet%20at%20a%20party,95